# Linux mail command removes text after space in subject when run from Java

Tags: java, linux, shell, email, centos

I have to send email from a Linux server through a Java program. When I run the command on SSH Secure Shell, everything is fine. But when I call the same command from Java, the subject after space is removed.

Script is as follows:

**mail -s "This is a test subject" "receiver@example.com"**

When I execute the above script through Java, the subject is truncated to **"This** (Double quotes followed by the first word)

Java code for running the above script is:

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec(emailCommand);**

*Here emailCommand refers to the shell script.

Did a lot of googling but did not find a solution.

Comment: Can you put the whole block of java codes how are you using it? Here you have put only one line of code. want to see what are all in emailCommand. Also provide mail command in the script.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(emailCommand);  is what I am using to execute the command given above (mail -s "This is a test subject" "receiver@example.com"). That's it.

Comment: There is nothing more to the mail command

Comment: can you provide me the string detail of emailCommand? are you using ProcessBuilder in java code?

Comment: I am not using a ProcessBuilder. The command is being executed as it is

Comment: I have provided you a solution. Try with that and let me know.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) your command line was just split using the StringTokenizer, so you should use instead `Runtime.exec(String[] cmdarray)` and split this command as you want (but now, don't specify quotes around the whole arg -- they are already separated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the discussion with I am providing you a solution like below:-

```
String[] command ={"/path/to/your/shellscript.sh", "shellscriptcommandlineparameter"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("/tmp/output.txt"));
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();       

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Try with this updated java code and you can see the output from your shell script in `output.txt` file.